# How do I evaluate an Xpath of an XpathResult?

Tags: javascript, xpath, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am wanting to scrape data from online stores such as Argos. Argos has cards for each of their products and so I would like to first get a list of all of the product card nodes and then access specific Xpaths on each of these nodes.

Using the below code I am able to get a list of all of the unique product cards on the page, however when I try to look at the 'name' Xpath on each of these products they all return the exact same node (the 'name' node of the very first product). What am I doing wrong?

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36');
await page.goto("https://www.argos.co.uk/clearance/toys/c:30299/clearance:true/opt/page:1");
await page.waitForXPath("//div[@data-test='component-product-card']")
let p = await page.evaluate( () => {
    const prods = document.evaluate("//div[@data-test='component-product-card']", document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null)
    while(prod = prods.iterateNext()){
        let name = document.evaluate("//a[@itemprop='name']", prod, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null)
    }
})
```

Comment: Why are you using a loop to get the items where you can just use a single XPath, your last one : `//a[@itemprop='name']` ? Since you're in a loop in the last part of your script shouldn't you use `.` before your XPath expression to indicate you're working from a context node ? `".//a[@itemprop='name']"` ?

Comment: Good point on the unnecessary loop - Think I had just moved it around so much trying to get it to work... And thank you so much for pointing out my stupidity with missing the `.`, just started with XPaths so clearly missing the obvious think. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help. Keep up the good work.:)